# Python operating on files in a folder - 'for file in folder'

Tags: python, file, memory, directory

I know a folder's path, and for every file in the folder I would like to do some operations. So essentially what I'm looking for is a `for file in folder` type of code that gives me access to the files in variables.

What is the Python way of doing this?

Thanks

EDIT - example: my folder will contain a bunch of XML files, and I have a python routine already to parse them into variables I need.

Comment: Look at `os.listdir` or `os.walk`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will allow you to access and print all the file names in your current directory:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
   print filename
```

The [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) module contains much more information about the various functions available. The [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir) function can also take any other paths you want to specify.

Comment: For the argument to os.listdir() could I pass in the path to my known directory?

Comment: @YoungMoney Yes, you can, I'll put some links into my answer for additional documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Does the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) library look helpful?

It will perform some pattern matching, and accepts both absolute and relative addresses.

```
>>> import glob
>>> for file in glob.glob("*.xml"):    # only loops over XML documents
        print file
```

Answer (score 0):

For people coming at this from a python version 3.5 or later, we now have the superior os.scandir() which has tremendous performance improvements over os.listdir()

For more information about the improvements/benefits, check out https://benhoyt.com/writings/scandir/

Comment: Hi CJ, this is not an answer to the question, you can leave such comments in the comment sections (as a thread of the main answer for example)

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was helpful information and I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to someone else's reply.